# GNU parallel with --joblog not updating process completion

Tags: shell, jenkins, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to run a job in the background using GNU `parallel`. It is working fine. 
The last line in *install-app.sh* is *"deployment completed"*.  It looks like the script completed successfully but failed to update *joblog.txt*.

*joblog.txt* is not getting updated on completion of script.  I can see the following in *joblog.txt*:

```
Seq     Host    Starttime       JobRuntime      Send    Receive Exitval Signal  Command
```

Command:

```
sem --id sme-install --joblog joblog.txt ./install-app.sh && 2>&1 | \
tee -a install.log
```

In *Jenkins* I see the following error:

```
deployment completed
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
```

Comment: I'm not even sure `--joblog` is applicable when you invoke `parallel` as `sem` - there would only ever be one job in it so it wouldn't be much of a log.

Comment: @MarkSetchell As far I know --joblog is running status of the command/script run.once job completed it has to be updated by gnu parallel and later checked by gnu parallel to output success or failure.

Comment: You will get getter answers if you follow stackoverflow.com/help/mcve